# How to find next record based on combobox "filter"

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with two comboboxes, the first (cboSet) picks a class set, the second (cboName) displays student names within that set (the ID is hidden in the 1st column). I have a button which I would like to use to find the next student in that set. I have tried implementing a next button which will go to the next record but not the correct student. Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: How did you try to create your next student button.  If you have any code in your attempts can you please post that as well. Screenshots would help as well.

Comment: ="[EnglishID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0)) At the moment that goes to the next record but I would like the next EnglishID which is the same set as the combobox. I've messed around with some variants of this but they haven't been successful... I'm new to this as you can probably tell ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you say next student, do you mean the student with the next numerical ID or are you using some other criteria for the next student?
here's one possible solution assuming that you want to filter your form with the next student.  Without more details this example is somewhat vague. Seeing what you already have would make it more precise.

in the onclick event of your button:

```
Dim ID as Integer

ID = me.cboName.column(0) + 1
me.filter = "[ID] = " & ID
me.filteron = true
```

to find the next value in your set you could do something like the following, Of course this is only generic, basic (hopefully someone correct) code, so you'll have to change it to suit your needs, but it should point you in the correct direction.

```
dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset
dim nextID as interger
dim SQLquery as string
nextID = 0

SQLquery = "SELECT TOP 1 ID from COMBO_RECORD_SOURCE WHERE ID > " & me.namecombo.column(0) & " ORDER BY ID"
set db = currentdb
set rs = db.openrecordset(SQLquery,dbOpenSnapshot)
if rs.recordCount > 0 THEN
   rs.movefirst //I know it's not strictly necessary, old habit I like to do..
   nextID = rs!ID
end if

if nextID > 0 then
  me.filter = "[ID] = " & nextID
  me.filteron = true
else
  msgbox "There are no more names in this set."
end if

set rs = nothing
set db = nothing
```

Comment: The form is based on a query which has the EnglishID, then the set then the name of the student. In the first combobox, you select the set and the second combobox updates with the relevant names. What I would like to do is click the button and the next student in the same set will appear. The English ID is in numerical order but I would like it to jump to the ID corresponding to the student in that set. Hope that helps.

Comment: The concept above will work, you just need to work out how to pull the ID of the next student in your set. How do you get the student's names in the combo box? via query. You should be able to find the next ID in the set by looking for the next largest ID in your query that is used as the recordsource. then filter as described above.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction to start please? I've been doing a little bit in the macro builder, would I use a tempVar and some sort of expression? At the moment, I've got a message box to display the current ID, perhaps I could start with that?

Comment: it isn't recognising the method openrecordsource

Comment: it's db.OpenRecordSet ... I just typed it out real quick and there are bound to be a couple of mistakes.

Comment: I really appreciate this, it's now saying too few parameters for that line of code (expected 1)

Comment: That usually means the recordsource you're pulling from is most likely built on a query that requires parameters. Recordsets don't like this. you'll have to recreate the query in VBA using SQL